# Unable to put 3 numbers which sum to 0 in a list

Tags: python

My list named `myList` is not getting updated.

I'm defining it inside a function and I'm using it inside that function

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        myList = []
        a = []
        for i in range(len(nums)):
           # print("---i",nums[i])
        #    print(a[0])
            for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
             #   print("----j",nums[j])
                for k in range(i+2,len(nums)):
                #    print("-----k",nums[k])
                    if nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k] == 0:
                        print("m into it now for i",nums[i],"j",nums[j],"k",nums[k])
                        print("oooo",myList)
                        a.append(nums[i])
                        a.append(nums[j])
                        a.append(nums[k])
                  #      print(myList)
                        myList.append(a)
                        print("....",myList)
                        print("---",a)
                        a.clear()
        print(myList)
```

Getting output as:

```
[[], [], [], []]
```

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but should it be `k in range(j+1,len(nums))` if you want to iterate through all combinations?

Answer (score 2):

Python treat everything as object.
When you have a list like:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
```

Here `my_list` is a reference to the the list `[1,2,3]` stored in memory.

Now if you pass `my_list` to any other function or use it in any other object like you have append the `a` in `myList`, so here basically python use this as reference to the original list. And now `myList` has stored the reference of `a` inside it.
That's why when you clear the contents of `a`, it also affects the content of `myList`.

You don't have to clear the content of list `a`. Just re-initialize it every time  in `for` loop like this.

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        myList = []
        for i in range(len(nums)):
           # print("---i",nums[i])
           # print(a[0])
            for j in range(i+1,len(nums)):
             # print("----j",nums[j])
                for k in range(i+2,len(nums)):
                    # print("-----k",nums[k])
                    if nums[i]+nums[j]+nums[k] == 0:
                        print("m into it now for i",nums[i],"j",nums[j],"k",nums[k])
                        print("oooo",myList)
                        a = []
                        a.append(nums[i])
                        a.append(nums[j])
                        a.append(nums[k])
                        # print(myList)
                        myList.append(a)
                        print("....",myList)
                        print("---",a)
        print(myList)
```

UPDATE:
As Artog mentioned in comments

You can easily see this in action by running `print(list(map(hex,map(id, myList))))` at the end of the function instead. This will show that the memory address is the same for all entries with the original code, but different with the new.

Comment: You can easily see this in action by running `print(list(map(hex,map(id, myList))))` at the end of the function instead. This will show that the memory address is the same for all entries with the original code, but different with the new